# Grouped thousands number formatting - Array from txt

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

I need a bit of assistance.

Script is getting data from txt/csv file on sever, and displaying as is

Data row:

```
Product1,XVY-56,275.83,1162570000.5,16476237.0,16476237.0
```

Numbers 16476237.0 and 1162570000.5 etc are problematic.

I wish to display them with grouped thousands: 16,476,237

```
if (($handle = fopen("data.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

print "<tr>";
print "<td>".$array[0][3]."</td>";
print "<td>".$array[0][5]."</td>";
print "<td>".$array[0][4]."</td>";

print "</tr>";


  }
  print "</table>";

  fclose($handle);

}
```

What would be the best and quickest approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `number_format("xxxxx")`. It's a predefined `php function`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example with this array above? I'm still learning :)

Comment: If you are not using windows you have option to use : http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Product1,XVY-56,275.83,1162570000.5,16476237.0,16476237.0` are your array values then it should be like:

```
$arr = array('Product1','XVY-56','275.83','1162570000.5','16476237.0','16476237.0');
foreach($arr as $a){
    if((float)$a){
        $array[] = number_format($a,2);
    }else{
        $array[] = $a;
    }
}
print_r($array);
```